# Constraint involving a stochastic matrix and its inverse

Tags: matrices, stochastic-matrices

Consider the following feasibility problem:

> Find an $n \times n$ stochastic matrix $L$ such that $L^{-1} M L x$ is a non-negative vector, where $M$ is a known $n \times n$ positive matrix and $x$ is an $n$-dimensional probability vector (i.e., elements of $x$ add to $1$ and are non-negative).
>
> (By stochastic matrix $L$, I mean each row of $L$ sums to $1$ and each element is non-negative).

Can the above problem be formulated as a convex feasibility problem using Schur complements? To make the problem more tractable, one can add a constraint that $L$ is symmetric positive definite, if required.

Comment: It relates to symmetries of of the dynamic programming equation for a Markov decision process.  Note: small typo in my problem statement. I need the transpose of L to be a stochastic matrix.

Comment: Is $x$ also known?

Comment: Do you mean M is a positive definite matrix, as opposed to all elements are positive? If latter, then L= identity matrix is always a feasible solution. if not, I don't see how to formulate as a convex feasibility problem. You need something like $MLx == Ly, y >= 0$ with another provision that L be invertible. If you decide to require L be symmetric positive definite, the problem can be formulated as a Blinear Matrix Inequality (BMI). If local solver, such as PENLAB, finds feasible solution, you're done, otherwise you can try a global solver, such as YALMIP's bmibnb w/ PENLAB as upper solver.

Comment: If $Lx = v$ is *the* right Perron eigenvector of $M$ (this is defined up to positive scalar multiple, since $M$ is assumed positive---presumably this means all the entries are strictly positive), then $L^{-1}ML x = x$. So it suffices to find row stochastic $L$ such that  $Lx$ is a scalar multiple of $v$. Isn't this straightfoward?